# How can i make a hotkey in visual c#?

Tags: c#

So what I'm trying to do is when I press a certain key, it will send keys. This is what I have so far. When I click F1 it doesn't do anything, and I'm not sure why.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("Example Text");
            }
}
```

Comment: Set the Form's `KeyPreview = true`. Note that `F1` is the standard shortcut to activate the `Help` functionality. The string is sent to the active object: if you send it to a Button, you'll have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
}

void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("F1 is pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ill try it out now.